Thread safe replacement of value in Dictionary
Let's say that I have Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<int>> and:
Task1 tried to replace value under some key.
Task2 loops through elements that are in value under the same key.
Is this thread safe? I assume it should be if I first get the value and then loop though it in Task2. Task2 in this case should either get old value or new value, but I think it should never generate any thread exceptions.

What is the actual type of the IEnumerable<int>s that are stored as values in the dictionary? And what exactly do you mean by "tried to replace value under some key"? Could you edit the question and provide the code that does that?

When discussing thread safety, you need to be very precise and specific. Short answer "no". Longer answer "it could be, if you work at it, but it would be better to redesign this a bit".
In terms of the dictionary, if we assume that you're mutating the dictionary: we need to consider a get vs a set, competing. That is not thread safe unless you synchronize over the individual operations - you could absolutely see exceptions when accessing a dictionary concurrently if at least one access is a mutation. But frankly: it might make more sense to use ConcurrentDictionary<,> instead.
Separately, we need to consider enumeration of the sequence, IEnumerable<int>. Now; IEnumerable<int> does not guarantee to be repeatable, and the fact that it is in a lookup means you're probably planning on enumerating it multiple times, so: that's not ideal. Many types that implement IEnumerable<T> are repeatable, but it isn't an API guarantee. Further: many of those types are themselves mutable, and therefore not necessarily thread-safe vs changes to those types.
So: if it was me, I might consider using ConcurrentDictionary<string, ImmutableArray<int>> or ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReadOnlyMemory<int>>, and then I'd feel confident that it is safe...
...as long as no-one uses reflection or unsafe code, in which case all bets are off!

"and then I'd feel confident that it is reasonably safe." -- If I ever read a comment like this in an author's source code, my confidence about the correctness of their code would drop significantly. There is no such thing as "reasonably safe". It's either safe or not.

@TheodorZoulias that sentence needs to be considered in the context of what comes after the ellipsis (which is an unavoidable caveat that applies to literally everything in the runtime/framework); but yes, I was perhaps unclear. I will erase the word "reasonably", if it makes you feel better. Hopefully the actual main copy helps justify that!
